# XSLT - check attribute is exist or not

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT. this may be a simple question,

example : XML

```
<doc>
   <sec id="sec_2" sec-type="norm-refs">
</doc>
```

I need to know is there any `<sec>` node containing attribute `sec-type='node-refs'`, exist or not in original XML document.

Comment: Could I ask, what is your strategy for learning the language? Have you read any books or tutorials? Or is it your plan simply to ask questions on StackOverflow whenever you need more information? (If you want to avoid people thinking this, a good plan is to show in your question that you have made an effort, e.g. by showing what you tried that didn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple XPath:

```
//sec[@type="norm-refs"]
```

The `@` symbol indicates that you want an attribute that matches, not an element. The square brackets indicate you want something that matches that but the selector returns what comes before the square brackets.